# Почему функция super().__init__() не работает так как должна

Tags: python, ооп

Вот мой первый код который работает правильно:

```
class sotrudnik:
    def __init__(self, name, work=None, salary=0):
        self.name=name
        self.work=work
        self.salary=salary

    def Raise(self, x):
        if type(x)==int or type(x)==float:
            self.salary += self.salary * x
            return self.salary
        else:
            raise TypeError

class manager(sotrudnik):
    def Raise(self, x, y):
        if type(x)==int or type(x)==float:
            self.salary += self.salary * x
            if self.work!=None:
                self.salary += self.salary * y
                return self.salary
            else: return self.salary
        else:
            raise TypeError
        
s=manager(1,1,100)
print(s.Raise(0.1, 0.1))
```

Интерпретатор выводит: `121.0`

А вот мой второй код, при обработке которого компилятор выводит `None`:

```
class sotrudnik:
    def __init__(self, name, work=None, salary=0):
        self.name=name
        self.work=work
        self.salary=salary

    def Raise(self, x):
        if type(x)==int or type(x)==float:
            self.salary += self.salary * x
            return self.salary
        else:
            raise TypeError

class manager(sotrudnik):
    def Raise(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        if self.work!=None:
            self.salary += selfsalary * y
            return self.salary

ivan=manager('bdfy','quya',10000)
print(ivan.Raise(0.1, 0.1))
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему так

Comment: `super().__init__(x)` — вы не передали `work`, а значит `self.work` получает значение по умолчанию `None`, а значит условие `if self.work!=None:` является ложным, а значит метод ничего не возвращает

Comment: Ну и так как `salary` вы тоже не передали, то `self.salary` аналогично сбрасывается на значение по умолчанию `0`

Comment: И вообще вызывать `super().__init__` изнутри не-init метода выглядит как плохой код, что эта строчка здесь забыла вообще?